# How to align text in HTML select to the right?

Tags: html, css

The `text-align: right` has no effect. I saw adivse to use `dir="rtl"` it kinda works, but sometimes reverses the text (like in example below).

So, how to do it?

In the example below the "<=" will be rendered as "=>".

```html
<select dir="rtl">
  <option>&lt;=</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "text-align-last" instead

```css
select {
  text-align-last: right;
}

/* for demonstration purpose only */
select {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>&lt;=</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, had no idea those css attribute exists :)

Answer (score 1):

simply use `text-align: right;` within CSS.

```css
select {
  text-align: right;
}

/* for demonstration purpose only */
select {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>&lt;=</option>    
</select>
```

`direction: rtl` is for languages that actually read from right to left like arabic, japanese...

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, please check your code, the `text-align: right` has no effect.

Comment: @Spectric please see the updated question, I just want to align text to the right, but the text align with CSS doesn't work.

Comment: within my snippet it works flawlessly as itnended. the text is aligned at the right side. I really dont get what you mean.